# Problems connecting to a local MySQL database using C# and .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, visual-studio-2010

Newb questions incoming.

I'm running MySQL locally and I am having a really hard time connecting to it with C#.

Here's the code I'm using, much of the stuff I've tried out is commented out:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Data.Common.DbConnection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
namespace mvpde
{
    class Program
    {
        class DataReader_SQL
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //
                // TODO: Add code to start application here
                //
                try
                {

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=127.0.0.1:3306;database=database_name;User id=id;Password=password;");
                    con.Open();

                    //Thread.Sleep(9999);

                    //SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                    //builder.DataSource = "localhost";
                    //builder.UserID = "hello";
                    //builder.Password = "password";
                    //builder.InitialCatalog = "db_123";

                    //SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
                    //thisConnection.Open();
                    //SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
                    //thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers";
                    //SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    //while (thisReader.Read())
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", thisReader["CustomerID"], thisReader["CompanyName"]);
                    //}
                    //thisReader.Close();
                    //thisConnection.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Thread.Sleep(9999999);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've copied it nearly verbatim and tried to make it work from [this site](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/21636/how-do-you-connect-to-a-sql-database-using-c).

I have installed the MySQL on Windows 7 - I have created the user and the database I'm trying to access and I can do all this just fine using MySQL's own MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE software. I seem to have no clue what I'm doing using C# to connect to it.

All I want is to connect to it and send it a simple query like "USE DATABASE somedb" and then "SELECT TABLE sometable".

Errors I'm getting: 
At first (when I used WAMP, before installing the MySQL package from mysql website) I would be able to connect once and see a login error; after that, it's as if the connection wasn't closed properly and I'd be unable to get even that far)
Now that I'm trying to connect to a MySQL instance that is created by MySQL's own software (or by running mysqld.exe) all I ever get is timeout problems\server not found\inaccessible.

Questions:

- Am I using the wrong class?
- What's the deal with "Provider="? where is the list of all the available variables for that part of the string? What does it mean? Why are the names involved so cryptic?

I imagined connecting to a locally-running MySQL server should be a breeze, but I've no idea what I'm doing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the MySql/Connector for DotNet.
Download it at [this address](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) then change your connection string accordingly.
For example  "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=database_name;Uid=id;Pwd=password;Port=3306"
For other options, specific for MySQL, look at [www.connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/mysql#p28)

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for your input - what if I can't download a library? Is there a way to do this only with what .NET 2.0 provides?

Comment: Of course, this connector has its classes, so you need to change SqlCommand in MySqlCommand etc etc. and add a reference to your project and insert a using MySql.Data.MySqlClient in every source file where needed. Not difficult, but can't be helped

Comment: Instead, if you wish to remain with OleDB (really you shouldn't) the connection string is "Provider=MySQLProv;Data Source=127.0.0.1:3306;User Id=id;Password=password;"

Comment: So are you implying that bare-bones .NET 2.0 doesn't have anything terribly useful for what I'm trying to do and that I need to download and use other libraries to connect and then send queries to the DB? Is this a fair assertion?

Comment: No, you could use OleDb (or ODBC) as you are trying, but sometimes you could hit a roadblock that prevents you to access the full power of your database. So, if possible, use the connector provided by the database vendor. (Microsoft->Sql, Oracle->OraClient, MySql->MySql/Connector).

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. In my hypothetical situation I will only have access to .NET 2.0 and a file called "libmysql.dll" - how would I find out which of those (I'm assuming) connectors it is if any? Chances are it might be easier \ better than OleDb... however like I said I will only have to run a couple of very simple queries.

Comment: "libmysql.dll" is a unmanaged library and it's not easy to use from C#, you need to read a lot of docs. For a couple of queries, stick to OleDb. It should works. However you still need to download the library with MySqlProv provider

Answer (score 1):

have you had a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a SQL Connection object.  You need a MySQL Connection object which is available in this library.http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Download the MySQL Connection Library and use one of their connection strings provided on the site.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection;();
myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
myConnection.Open();
//execute queries, etc
myConnection.Close();
```

Then use the connection object to initalise the connection string and connect to MySQL

Comment: This is kind of off the wall, but what if I can't use any third-party libraries and just sort of have to roll with everything that's available in .NET 2.0 and only that?

Comment: Scratch that, I will have access to a file called libmysql.dll - that's about it for my options.

Comment: You will have to reference that dll in your project and look through the object browser of methods/properties it provides.  It should have basic properties/methods such as connection string, connect, execute query etc.

Comment: Are you implying that bare-bones .NET 2.0 doesn't have anything terribly useful for what I'm trying to do and that I need to download and use other libraries (or use the one that I just mentioned) to connect and then send queries to the DB? Is this a fair assertion?

Comment: You can still connect to MySQL via OLEDB however it would be easier to use the library I provided. 
Here is a C# tutorial on connecting to MySQL via OLEDB:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Database-Programming-in-C-Sharp-with-MySQL-Using-OleDB/